# django framework can't create authentication token in google cloud

Tags: python, django, authentication, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I can't create a token for an user manually throught django admin site (https://admin/).

I have built an user accounts on a django framework allocated in google cloud server, as a GAE app. In order to add user accounts I use a third-party app for django called "rest_framework", the problem comes when I try to create a token for a created user in admin site, error 500 appear and no idea how to find the problem. The framework also has been tested on a local machine (my computer) and works correctly, but for some reason it doesn't work in google cloud.

The added code of each file is showing as follows:

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = ...

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',

    'KhalilApp.apps.KhalilappConfig',   #This is my app on django

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoServer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'KhalilApp/Mapilib'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'KhalilApp/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoServer.wsgi.application'

import pymysql
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0) 
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '...',
            'USER': '...',
            'PASSWORD': '...',
            'NAME': '...',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '...',
            'NAME': '...',
            'USER': '...',
            'PASSWORD': '...',
        }
    }

# [END db_setup]
if os.getenv('TRAMPOLINE_CI', None):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
        }
    }

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
   ),
}
```

KhalilApp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    #url('app-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^auth/', ObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
]
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

views.py

```
...
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permissioon_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Then, when I try to create a token for a user here
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DesF0.png) an error 500 appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK2lc.png). Any idea how to solve this problem?

REEDIT:
Traceback are showing as follows:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://.../admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.sites',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'corsheaders',
 'KhalilApp.apps.KhalilappConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)

The above exception ((1146, "Table 'principal.authtoken_token' doesn't exist")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1693, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 735, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 94, in count
    return c()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 515, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 500, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'principal.authtoken_token' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Hi @rodrigo, please share the complete error traceback of the error in question instead of image. Also, from the images I able to understand that you are running the code in production mode.  Is it possible for you to set `DEBUG = True` in the settings and then share the traceback?

Comment: Hi @VJMagar and thank you for response. I will change DEBUG variable as soon as possible. Traceback is located in logs, right?

Comment: If you turn on the debug, then the complete trackback is returned with the response, i.e., your 500 page itself will contain the trackback

Comment: Sorry for the delay @VJMagar, finally I get a traceback. I reedit the question in order to add this traceback.

Comment: It's already, don't be sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the trackback, I am able to understand that the `principal.authtoken_token` table doesn't exist.

```
The above exception ((1146, "Table 'principal.authtoken_token' doesn't exist")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Try

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

let me know if this resolves the issue

Comment: just in case: @Rodrigo remember to set the `debug= false` when making it available for production :)